# Proof explanation of $5^{2n}-2^n$ is divisible by $23$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: analysis, induction, proof-explanation

I want to understand the proof of

$$5^{2n}-2^n \text{ is divisble by } 23 \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}$$

$$\text{Base case: } n = 0 \Rightarrow5^{2\cdot 0}-2^0 = 1-1 =0 ; 0 \text{  is divisble by 23}$$

$$\text{Hypothesis: The proposition holds for }n \in \mathbb{N}, \text{ so } 5^{2n}-2^n = q \cdot 23, q \in \mathbb{N}$$

$$\text{Induction step:} 5^{2(n+1)} - 2^{n+1} = 5^{2n+2} - 2 \cdot 2^n = 25 \cdot 5^{2n}- 2 \cdot 2^n = 2 \cdot (5^{2n}-2^n) +23 \cdot 5^{2n} $$

$$= \text{(IH) } 2 \cdot 23q+23 \cdot5^{2n} = 23\cdot(2q+5^{2n}) \Rightarrow \text{ Is divisible by 23}$$

What I don't get is why $25 \cdot 5^{2n}- 2 \cdot 2^n = 2 \cdot (5^{2n}-2^n) +23 \cdot 5^{2n}= 2 \cdot 23q+23 \cdot5^{2n}$.

Comment: $25=2+23$. Does that help?

Comment: $25a+2b = (2+23)a + 2b = 2a+23a+2b = 2a+2b+23a = 2(a+b)+23a$

Comment: by the way, $5^2\equiv2\pmod{23}$

Comment: Thank you all! Now I understand.